# Are oblique shocks formed at the leading edge-top surface of a wing?

Tags: aerodynamics, supersonic, fluid-mechanics, shock-waves

Do oblique shocks form on the leading upper surface of a wing? I know bow shocks are formed there, but is that the same thing as I’m talking about? Oblique shocks would have to form there because the air turns into itself due to the airfoil curve, (at Mach speeds of course). Thanks.

Comment: You should know by now that by a pointy body an oblique shock wave (or compression expansion) forms, while by a blunt body a detached shock forms. Those are two different phenomena: behind an oblique shock wave the speed is still supersonic, while behind a detached shock the speed is subsonic. Which of the two is going to happen depends on the geometry of the leading edge.